# Running off of UIthread without AsyncTask 

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, handler

I have a task that takes about 10 seconds on the UI thread during initialization of my app, I decided to instead put this in a background thread and show a splash screen while this was going on.. I got this working using AsyncTask... however because of AsyncTasks priority being hard coded so low, and no way to increase it that I can find, the task went from taking 10 seconds to finish, to several minutes.

So, the question I have is, how do I run a task on a NON UI thread without AsyncTask?  Everything I have tried to so far seems to run on the UI Task which prevents the SplashScreen from appearing until after the task is done.

So how do I create a thread, run it on a non UI thread?  I assume there must be an option other than AsyncTask but so far I have not found it... handlers just seem to run on the UI, as do standard threads/runnables.  This has to be possible, but I am just not figuring it out.

Comment: What about posting `Runnable` to a `Handler`?  It may be doing the same thing, but I'm not sure.  I wouldn't be surprised though if Android has this hard notion that everything not on UI thread is very low priority.

Comment: I tried the runnable to a handler originally, before goin ASYNC but it just ran on the UI, so the splashscreen never appeared.

Comment: Houcine, maybe I am not understanding the runonuithread method, but how is that going to help me?  Whenever I run this code on the UI thread the splashscreen never appears, until after the work is done, so how is moving it into its own thread, and then saying run this on the UI thread going to help the situation?

Comment: My basic code I want is this:
on create, make dialog, show dialog, setContext to my real main view (under the dialog), go copy the file, dismiss dialog and show my main view..    If I put the copy in a handler, no dice, Splash screen never appears, if I put the co copy the file in an async thread, and the dismiss call in the onpost processing, it does work, but as I said, it takes 5 minutes to copy the file.

Comment: I need the oncreate to complete, so that my view and the dialog appear, but I need the copy to happen as well.. ASYCN does this, it moves the copy into a thread off the UI, so oncreate can finish, so my views show up.. but it just takes forever because its priority is so low.. when I used a handler, runnable model, it ran the thread on the UIThread so oncreate didn't finish until the copy finished, even though it was in its own thread, the thread was running on the UI, so the oncreate completion was blocked until the copy completed.

Comment: @Houcine  Thanks for the suggestion, I think I understand what you were suggesting, you were suggesting in my runinBackground, telling it to run on the UI... so that the oncreate would have completed, but then I could have stuck this on the UI to run with priority.. that might have worked, but I think the answer I accepted is more what I was looking for, I just needed to bump the priority of the running thread up, and the call suggested there does exactly what I needed.  Thank youf or the help.

Comment: you are welcome , we are here to help , by the way  , i means by using the runOnUIThread () , you can launch your thread and on your method run , u can use the runOnUIThread to force the UIThread to show the splash , and then your thread will continue his work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you already got the `AsyncTask` working, maybe you could just bump it's priority from inside `doInBackground()`:

```
protected Void doInBackground() {
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    /* do the work */
}
```

Also, for the `Handler`, not exactly sure what the problem was, but you need to create the `Handler` in the UI thread, explicitly start a different thread to do your work, then use the handler from that new thread to post messages to the UI thread. `AsyncTask` is nice because it takes care of all this for you.

Comment: Thanks Steve, that's what I was looking for.. I knew there had to be some way to bump the asynctask priority, but I just wasn't seeing it.  Worked like a charm, thanks.

Comment: This increases priority only after doInBackground() is called. I got an issue where the doInBackground() itself is called 10 seconds later. Finally used thread and dropped Asynctask.

Comment: @SteveBlackwell I wouldn't recommend to use Thread.MAX_PRIORITY. I'd prefer android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND + android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE which would lift the Thread out of the background group while still significantly preferring the User Interface Thread. Using Thread.MAX_PRIORITY, you might annoy people who leave their Internet radio on while using your app.

Comment: ...adding that the priorities from the android.os.Process class should not be used with methods from the Thread class. Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_...) must be used.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a `Thread`, set any priority you want and `start()` it. Or use a `Runnable` and an `Executor`. Those will not run on the UI thread. If you need to notify the UI when your background work is done, create a `Handler` before starting the thread and pass it to your `Thread/Runnable`.